# SQL SEARCHING relational database

Tags: mysql

given a users qualification id's how would you find the jobs they can do using SQL?

1) for example a user with only qualification 1 could only do job3
and not 1 and 4 because you need more than one qualification.
2) a user with qualifications 1 and 2 could do jobs 1 and 3 but not 4

JOBDETAILS TABLE

JobID ,QualificationID

1, 1

1, 2

3, 1

4, 1

4, 2

4, 3

thanks for any help

TJ

Comment: you need to provide us info on your user table to write the full pseudo-query

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT JobID
FROM JobDetails
WHERE QualificationID IN (@Quals)
AND JobID NOT IN
(
  SELECT DISTINCT JobID
  FROM JobDetails
  WHERE QualificationID NOT IN (@Quals)
)
```

(Apologies for syntax issues; I work with SQL Server, not MySQL)